# PowerShell/.NET 4 GUIs - Internal Windows Icons?

Tags: .net, powershell

Let me preface this question with first stating that I'm new to GUI interfaces:  what's available, what can/can't be done, etc.  With that being said, here we go!

I'm writing a PowerShell gui using System.Windows.Form objects and wanted to know if there are ICONS available in some inherent library available in Windows that I can invoke programmatically so that I don't have to manually create?

As an example, I'm looking to add little question-mark "?" icons next to some of my fields that would serve as like a mouse-over style help explaining specifics about x or y field.

Does such a thing exist?  If so, does anyone have a good doc on what icons are available and how to invoke them in PowerShell?  If not, does anyone have a solid work-around for what I'm describing?

Edit:

So I found out how to do this.  You use the System.Drawing.SystemIcons and assign the invoked icon into the .Icon property of an object (if it has one).

```
form1.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Question
```

I was hoping for something I could use in any control but I suppose this will work.

Comment: Glad to see you liked the answer. You can convert Icons to Bitmaps via the Icon.ToBitmap() method, by the way! That makes them even more useful. Code sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.tobitmap.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There sure is such a thing. I used it to create a MessageBox with selectable and copyable text once. You're looking for the **System.Drawing.SystemIcons** class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemicons.aspx

Here are some guidelines to using such icons: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511277.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On each windows system you can find ressource files with icons used by the shell `Explorer.exe`.

From Windows NT 3.1 to 5.2 (W2K3 or XP) ressources are in :

```
C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll
```

Beginig NT 6.0 (Vista) they are in :

```
C:\Windows\System32\Imageres.dll
```

You can open these files with Visual Studio as ressources files to find the Shell Icons you need.

Answer (score 0):

One trick I've found is the use of the Webdings and Wingdings fonts.  Both are universally available on about every OS/SKU since 2000.  They have an astounding amount of simple iconography you can pick from.

I'll do a blog post describing some of the ones I've found and add a comment with a link.

Hope this Helps